# Lyx \usepackage doesn't enable package physics - inserting a ket doesn't work

Tags: lyx, preamble

I have a Lyx document with the preamble:
\usepackage{physics}

and one line of code (in math mode):
\ket{\phi}

However it doesn't render the ket - it shows the backslash and the tag "ket" and the greek letter.

Similar results with the package braket.

Answer (score 1):

It was necessary to enable "Instant Preview" in Tools |Preferences